# App not installing in Android 11 but works on previous versions

Tags: android, build, build.gradle, apk

I have an app with two packages `com.example.package` and `com.other.package`. My configurations in build.gradle is as follows:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.package"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 30
```

I build an unsigned release build. Then I sign it with

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore <keystore> <OUTPUT> <ALIAS>
```

The build I get from this works well on all versions except for Android 11.
On android 11 when I install my app I get the following error:

```
adb: failed to install ginger-uk.apk: Failure [-124: Failed parse during installPackageLI: Targeting R+ (version 30 and above) requires the resources.arsc of installed APKs to be stored uncompressed and aligned on a 4-byte boundary]
```

So I tried zip aligning the APK and installing but then I get the following error on Android 11:

```
App not installed error
```

I then tried to zipalign first before signing based on some stackoverflow solution but I get the following error on Android 11:

```
adb: failed to install ginger-uk.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Scanning Failed.: No signature found in package of version 2 or newer for package com.other.package]
```

My Question is has anyone successfully signed an APK for android 11 and below? and how do you do this?

Answer (score 25):

This could be related: Android 11 no longer supports APK Signature Scheme v1. The apk must now be signed using APK Signature Scheme v2 or higher.
Refer to this link for further information: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/behavior-changes-11#minimum-signature-scheme

Answer (score 6):

I solved this, the problem was `resources.arsc` was `BAD` after using `jarsigner`, So I zip aligned and then used `apksigner` to sign it. This fixes this issue (atleast for me).

Comment: what is "zip aligned"?

Comment: @AdarshMadrecha : This could be helpful -  https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/zipalign

Answer (score 4):

Just check the V2 (Full APK Signature).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For those using MS AppCenter to do builds, you need to delete and redo the build configuration, including uploading your keystore file again.
You can check for the correct signing used by looking at the log

```
Task         : Android signing
Description  : Sign and align Android APK files
Version      : 3.193.0  <-- must be larger than 1.x
```

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/1990#issuecomment-861053082

Comment: This is a time saver, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Its documented by Google. If you are using apksigner, then you need to zipalign and then sign the APK.

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner

> Caution: If you sign your APK using apksigner and make further changes
> to the APK, the APK's signature is invalidated. Therefore, you must
> use tools such as zipalign before signing your APK.