# Repackage APK with Adobe AIR

Tags: android, flash, air, ane

There is an Android game made in Flash that was packaged using Adobe AIR, but it no longer works for Android versions above 7. I was wondering if it is possible to repackage this game using [HARMAN's Adobe AIR](https://airsdk.harman.com/download)?

I have downloaded [HARMAN's Adobe AIR](https://airsdk.harman.com/download) and attempted to repackage the application using the [ADT package command](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d128cdca935b-8000.html). I used the `application.xml` file that was present in the APK's `assets/META-INF/AIR/` folder. However, this application uses extensions, and it appears that ADT expects ANE (AIR Native Extension) files, or is there some other way?

I couldn't find the ANE files online. But some Chinese hackers were able to repackage the app, working in Android 10, and the folder `assets/META-INF/AIR/extensions` folder has suffered no changes in comparison with the original apk. The files in the folder `lib/armeabi-v7a` were updated however, and include a new one called `libX86Bridge.so`.

The extensions that the original app uses are:

- com.adobe.ane.social
- com.milkmangames.extensions.AndroidIAB
- com.chartboost.plugin.air
- com.milkmangames.extensions.CoreMobile
- com.jirbo.airadc.AirAdColony
- com.milkmangames.extensions.GoViral

Comment: If the original app included external ANE files then repackaging will require the same (or up to date versions) of the same files. Unless you change the app so the ANE files are not required.

Comment: @crooksy88 Added more information to my question to answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I have finally been able to repackage the APK, and it works on recent Android versions!

First, I opened the APK file with an archive manager (APK is a ZIP file), and then converted the `classes.dex` file inside the APK to a JAR file, using the [dex2jar](https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar) tool. Inside the JAR file (which is also a ZIP file) are the compiled Java classes from the AIR Native Extensions that the app uses.

Then, inside the `bin` directory of [Adobe AIR by HARMAN](https://airsdk.harman.com/download) I created a directory for each extension:

```
AIRSDK_Windows\bin
├── com.adobe.ane.social
├── com.milkmangames.extensions.AndroidIAB
├── com.chartboost.plugin.air
├── com.milkmangames.extensions.CoreMobile
├── com.jirbo.airadc.AirAdColony
├── com.milkmangames.extensions.GoViral
```

The unpacked extension ANEs could be found inside the APK, in the path `/assets/META-INF/AIR/extensions/`.

For each extension, added `catalog.xml` and `library.swf` into a ZIP file, and renamed the ZIP extension to SWC (e.g.: `com.adobe.ane.social.swc`). Then, placed the SWC file inside the respective extension's directory.

Inside each extension's directory in the APK, there is a path `META-INF/ANE/` where the file `extension.xml` and other files can be found (e.g.: `/assets/META-INF/AIR/extensions/com.adobe.ane.social/META-INF/ANE/`). I placed all the files inside these directories in the directories of the respective extensions that I created in the `bin` directory. For the `com.chartboost.plugin.air` extension, for example, this is what the directory structure looks like:

```
AIRSDK_Windows\bin
├── com.adobe.ane.social
├── com.milkmangames.extensions.AndroidIAB
├── com.chartboost.plugin.air
│   ├── com.chartboost.plugin.air.swc
│   ├── extension.xml
│   ├── Android-ARM
├── com.milkmangames.extensions.CoreMobile
├── com.jirbo.airadc.AirAdColony
├── com.milkmangames.extensions.GoViral
```

I opened the `extension.xml` file, and these were its contents:

```xml
<extension xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/extension/16.0">
    <id>com.chartboost.plugin.air</id>
    <versionNumber>5.5.0</versionNumber>
    <platforms>
        <platform name="Android-ARM">
            <applicationDeployment>
                <nativeLibrary>libChartboostAir.jar</nativeLibrary>
                <initializer>com.chartboost.plugin.air.ChartboostExtension</initializer>
                <finalizer>com.chartboost.plugin.air.ChartboostExtension</finalizer>
            </applicationDeployment>
        </platform>
        
        <platform name="iPhone-ARM">
            <applicationDeployment>
                <nativeLibrary>libChartboostAir.a</nativeLibrary>
                <initializer>ChartboostExtInitializer</initializer>
                <finalizer>ChartboostExtFinalizer</finalizer>
            </applicationDeployment>
        </platform>
        
        <platform name="default">
            <applicationDeployment/>
        </platform>
        
    </platforms>
</extension>
```

As I am not packaging the game for `iPhone-ARM` nor do I have the `libChartboostAir.a` file, I commented that `platform` block using XML comments `<!--  -->`.

We can see that there is a `default` platform (I noticed that all extensions have one). So, I created a directory for the `default` platform and copied `library.swf` from the `Android-ARM` directory to it. Then placed both directories inside a `platform` directory. The directory structure now looks like this:

```
AIRSDK_Windows\bin
├── com.adobe.ane.social
├── com.milkmangames.extensions.AndroidIAB
├── com.chartboost.plugin.air
│   ├── com.chartboost.plugin.air.swc
│   ├── extension.xml
│   ├── platform
│   │   ├── Android-ARM
│   │   │   ├── library.swf
│   │   │   ├── <other bunch of files>
│   │   ├── default
│   │   │   ├── library.swf
├── com.milkmangames.extensions.CoreMobile
├── com.jirbo.airadc.AirAdColony
├── com.milkmangames.extensions.GoViral
```

Then, from the JAR file that we got at the beginning (converted from `classes.dex`), I got all the classes related to `com.chartboost.plugin.air` and placed them in a ZIP archive named `libChartboostAir.jar`. I then placed `libChartboostAir.jar` inside the `Android-ARM` directory.

Finally, for this extension, I ran the following command to generate the ANE file:

```
..\adt.bat -package -target ane com.chartboost.plugin.air.ane extension.xml -swc com.chartboost.plugin.air.swc -platform Android-ARM -C platform/Android-ARM . -platform default -C platform/default library.swf
```

I generated the ANE files for the other extensions following the above steps. At the end, there were some classes in the JAR file (generated from `classes.dex`) that I hadn't placed in the JAR file from any extension, because I did not know where they belonged. So, I just placed them in a random extension's JAR file. This wasn't a problem because what matters is that all classes end up being placed in the new `classes.dex` file, using the same directory structure as the original.

Once all ANE files were compiled, I created a directory in the `bin` directory for the app that I want to repackage.

Inside the original APK's `assets` directory, there were the app's SWF file and a `_Pic_Gen` directory with the app's icons. I placed them both in the directory I just created. And in the original APK's `/assets/META-INF/AIR/` directory there were an `application.xml` file and an `extensions` directory (with the unpacked ANEs). I placed the `application.xml` file inside the directory I created for the app in the `bin` directory. Inside this directory, I also created an `extensions` directory and placed the compiled ANE files inside. So, the directory structure for this app now looks like this:

```
AIRSDK_Windows\bin
├── MyApp
│   ├── application.xml
│   ├── _Pic_Gen
│   ├── MyApp.swf
│   ├── extensions
│   │   ├── com.adobe.ane.social.ane
│   │   ├── com.milkmangames.extensions.AndroidIAB.ane
│   │   ├── com.chartboost.plugin.air.ane
│   │   ├── com.milkmangames.extensions.CoreMobile.ane
│   │   ├── com.jirbo.airadc.AirAdColony.ane
│   │   └── com.milkmangames.extensions.GoViral.ane
```

I changed the `targetSdkVersion` in the manifest inside `application.xml` to 30, in order to support Android 11 (currently the latest). Android version and SDK correlation: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms

I also changed `<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/17.0">` to `<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/33.1">`, so that it uses the latest Flash Player version (33.1 is from HARMAN).

Then, I created a self-signed certificate using OpenSSL (I used Linux for this):

```sh
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -x509 -keyout cakey.pem -out cacert.pem -days 10000
# entered my password
openssl pkcs12 -export -in cacert.pem -inkey cakey.pem -out myapp.p12
```

And finally, I could package the new APK, using:

```
..\adt.bat -package -target apk -storetype pkcs12 -keystore myapp.p12 MyApp.apk application.xml -extdir extensions MyApp.swf _Pic_Gen
# entered certificate's password
```

**Edit 2021-05-19** (**Edit 2022-02-19**: This step is no longer necessary with the latest Adobe AIR by HARMAN.)

However, for Android 11 and above, the APK must now be signed using APK Signature Scheme v2 or higher (see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66041713/3049315). Using `apksigner` (available in Android SDK), you may do this as follows:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\<version>\apksigner.bat sign -v --out MyApp_v2signed.apk --ks myapp.p12 MyApp.apk
```

The APK was then generated and I could play the game on recent Android versions.

**Edit 2021-06-25**

Apparently on some devices there would be an error on opening the APK saying "There was a problem parsing this package".

The error that I was getting when profiling the APK with Android Studio was: `INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_RESOURCES_ARSC_COMPRESSED`

Then I came across [this issue](https://github.com/airsdk/Adobe-Runtime-Support/issues/58) in AIR SDK. Opening `AIRSDK_Windows\lib\adt.cfg` showed me the commented line:
`#UncompressedExtensions=emd,tfl,tflite,pb`
I uncommented it and added the `arsc` extension to it, which is the extension of the file resources.arsc that Android Studio was complaining about. This fixed the issue after repackaging the APK with the new configuration.

**Edit 2022-02-11**

With the latest Adobe AIR, the following line should be added to the `application.xml` file under the `<android>` section  if one does not wish to use the Android SDK for building. See: https://github.com/airsdk/Adobe-Runtime-Support/issues/1527#issuecomment-1007293682

```xml
<BuildLegacyAPK>true</BuildLegacyAPK>
```

Another option is to use the Android SDK for building, in which case the following lines should be added in the file `AIRSDK_Windows\lib\adt.cfg` (replace with correct paths):

```
AndroidPlatformSDK=C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.14
```

Note that Java 11 or above must be used.

Furthermore, Android 12 now requires receivers with intent filters to have the attribute `android:exported`. Example:

```xml
<receiver android:name="com.milkmangames.extensions.android.CMBootReceiver" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```